# How to load JSON string into JSON column

Tags: mysql, json

I have MySQL table that I like to populate with load data infile.

One of the column is a JSON type, to which I want to upload an entire json string.  The problem is that it seems really hard to upload the json string, where I get:

```
Invalid utf8 character string: '{'
```

A row from my CSV file:

```
25621943694,john,johnny,ACTIVE,organization,1234,{\”name\”: \”cicd-prod\”},2016-10-22 16:57:36
```

My load data statement:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'test123.csv'
INTO TABLE projects 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' (project_number,project_id,project_name,lifecycle_state,parent_type,parent_id,raw_project,create_time);
```

Comment: It seems that `”` isn't a normal quote character.

Comment: You shouldn't have curly quotes in the JSON, they should be ASCII double quotes.

Comment: If you are trying to store the actual JSON string as your MySQL column it might be a good idea, if you are able, to modify the incoming JSON so the fields are delimited by single quotes.  That way you can store the entire JSON block as a MySQL string. i.e. `... 1234, "{ 'name':'cicd-prod'}",2016-10-22 16:57:36`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JSON, according to [the ECMA standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf), "*a string is a sequence of Unicode code points wrapped with quotation marks (U+0022).*"

Your CSV is not using [U+0022](https://unicode-table.com/en/0022/). It's using [U+0201D - Right Double Quotation Mark](https://unicode-table.com/en/201D/). It's not even using them correctly as I-cannot-put-enough-smart-quotes-around-“smart” quotes; its using the right quote for both the right and left sides.

Those quotes have to be converted back to a boring old U+0022 - Quotation Mark. And you need to have a chat with whomever generated that CSV. It's also possible an overzealous Office app mangled it.